# how do i make jpg file's name starts with number automatically increase python

Tags: python, file, ocr, naming, shutil

If there is same model name, it will be overwritten even if it's a different picture. So I want to name the image file in front of the name when it's made like 01, 02, 03...... but it doesn't work.
please help..

** text **is model name
** filename **is the original name of image file

this is using ocr and it supposed to make new image file name everytime when i use ocr one by one and this made me think for loop is not to use

```
mn = 0
File = open("modelImg/model.txt",'a')
print("result = {}".format(text))
File.write("result = {}\n".format(text))
File.close()
src = "../images/" + filename
mn += 1
dst = ("modelImg/"+"%i. "%mn+text +".jpg") 
shutil.copy(src,dst) 

return text
```

this is what i get...

[image: my result]

Comment: It's hard to help with just that code. What is `text` and `filename`?

Comment: text is model name and filename is the original name of image file

Comment: where is your for loop?

Comment: this is using ocr and it supposed to make new image file name everytime when i use ocr one by one and this made me think for loop is not to use

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code and output that you shared I am guessing that the error is because you have `mn = 0` inside the loop. And on every iteration of loop you are incrementing mn by 1 and then reassigning it to 0 again. So you are only getting 1 as a prefix for every file name.

If my assumption is correct then moving mn=0 outside the loop should solve your issue.